# C++: Losing a pointers value in a queue

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, queue

I'm making something that needs to work with a queue, enqueue and dequeue.
I made a simplified program(So i wont have to work with 12 classes) and it seems im getting the same problem.
I have a class that holds an int and a pointer to it, and while im doing the enqueue dequeue rotations i lose the pointers value and i cant solve this.
(I also need to make the queue myself so i cant use any libraries) 
I have the class 'son.cpp':

```
son::son() {
    random = 0;
}

void son::set_point() {
    point = &random;
}

son::son(son &other) {
    this->next = other.next;
    this->prev = other.prev;
    this->random = other.random;
}

void son::print_num() {
    std::cout << "Random number is: " << random << std::endl;
}
```

son.h:

```
class son {
public:
    int random;
    son* next;
    son* prev;
    int* point;
    son(son &other);
    son();
    void set_point();
    void print_num();
    ~son();
};
```

sonqueue.h:

```
class sonqueue{
    son *_head, *_tail;
public:
    sonqueue();
    bool isEmpty();
    son* dequeue();
    void enqueue(son&);
    ~sonqueue();
};
```

sonqueue.cpp:

```
sonqueue::sonqueue(){
    _tail = NULL;
    _head = NULL;
}

bool sonqueue::isEmpty() {
    if (_tail == NULL && _head == NULL)
        return true;
    return false;
}

son* sonqueue::dequeue() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        std::cerr <<"in queues head random "<< (_tail->point)<<std::endl;
        son *sp = new son(*_head);
        son *temp = sp->prev;
        delete _head;
        _head = temp;
        _head->next = NULL;
        return sp;
    }
    else {
        exit(5);
    }
}

void sonqueue::enqueue(son &ptr) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        _tail->prev = &ptr;
        (ptr.next) = _tail;
        _tail = &ptr;
        ptr.prev = NULL;
    }
    else {
        _tail = &ptr;
        _head = &ptr;
        ptr.prev = NULL;
        ptr.next = NULL;
    }
}

sonqueue::~sonqueue(){
    son *point = _tail;
    while (point->next != NULL) {
        son *to_be_del = dequeue();
        delete to_be_del;
    }
}
```

and the main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    sonqueue *sq = new sonqueue();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        son *son_to_be = new son();
        son_to_be->random = i;
        son_to_be->set_point();
        sq->enqueue(*son_to_be);
    }
    while (std::cin.get() != (char)27) {
        son *son_obj = sq->dequeue();
        son_obj->print_num();
        sq->enqueue(*son_obj);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I must be missing something because this code works perfectly with ints and such but when i try to do this with pointers i lose that value(As the address changes)
How can i implement this so it also carries the pointers value?

EDIT:
What i mean is when i try to go over the queue(enqueue-dequeue-enqueue...) I lose the value of point as its not going together with the other data members of the object(I believe because a it pointing to an address it doesnt copy the address)

Thanks

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, but when you copy a value, its address changes and hence any pointers that should point to the copy must also be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that it has to do with copying `son`-objects within queue-operations.
But as you already have a copy constructor in place, extending this with an adaption of `point` should solve your problem:

```
son::son(son &other) {
    this->next = other.next;
    this->prev = other.prev;
    this->random = other.random;
    this->point = &this->random;
}
```

There might be other issues as well, e.g. memory leaks, but that's not your question, right?